# PHPMailler is not working in some cases

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am sending mail with PHPmailer. The mail I send is working on Gmail. But it does not work in the account on mail.com. Does anyone know why? The result seems to be successful. But mail is not coming.

Example not working: `developer@chef.net`

Note: I'm using the same settings. My mail server on another server.

If the code I'm using is :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SetLanguage("tr", "class/language");
$mail->CharSet    = "utf-8";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host       = "example";
$mail->Port       = 25; // or 465
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->Username    = "example@example.com";
$mail->Password    = "example";
$mail->SetFrom($To[1], $To[0]);
$mail->Subject = 'example';

$mail->Body = 'example';
$mail->AddAddress($From[1], $From[0]);

if ($mail->Send()) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I was also redirected to my server CloudFlare.

PHPMailer Logs Output:

```
2018-04-24 11:24:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 centos.controlsunucu.com ESMTP Postfix
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO oxyn.org
2018-04-24 11:24:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-centos.controlsunucu.com
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-SIZE 10240000
                                      250-ETRN
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250 DSN
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-04-24 11:24:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO oxyn.org
2018-04-24 11:24:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-centos.controlsunucu.com
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-SIZE 10240000
                                      250-ETRN
                                      250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250 DSN
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH CRAM-MD5
2018-04-24 11:24:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 PDg0NDE4Mjc5NS4xNDYxOTU4NkBjZW50b3MuY29udHJvbHN1bnVjdS5jb20+
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: aW5mb0BkaXN0aWxlaWNraS5jb20gYWQ1MmQ2YjZjZTkzZTE3OTMzZDU5ZGNmNzZmNTJlYWY=
2018-04-24 11:24:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<apawebit@gmail.com>
2018-04-24 11:24:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Ok
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<developer@chef.net>
2018-04-24 11:24:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2018-04-24 11:24:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 14:24:49 +0300
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: =?utf-8?Q?=C3=96zg=C3=BCr_Can_KARAG=C3=96Z?= <developer@chef.net>
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: =?utf-8?Q?=C3=96zg=C3=BCr_Can_KARAG=C3=96Z?= <apawebit@gmail.com>
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Example
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <75ef49ca7263c41f42336be38def81f9@oxyn.org>
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: Example
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2018-04-24 11:24:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2018-04-24 11:24:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 918D133B8F
2018-04-24 11:24:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-04-24 11:24:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Comment: Define "Does not work". Are you putting user-supplied data in `$To`? Why are you disabling certificate checks?

Comment: I am sending mail to gmail, hotmail, yandex servers with settings I have made and it works. Mail.com does not work when sending an account. It's a return successful. But the mail does not come.

Comment: @Synchro CloudFlare is having trouble with its certifications. The values in the `$To` variable are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` to see the SMTP conversation, so you can be absolutely sure messages are being accepted and that you're not missing any interesting responses from the server. Beyond that, check your spam folder, and if your ISP is black-holing your messages, complain to them.

Your use of `$From` and `$To` looks to be the wrong way around, and it's not possible to tell if they are using user-supplied values - allowing a user to supply an address that you use as a `From` address is a sure way to get your email blocked or spam filtered since it's forgery and will break SPF and DMARC checks.

On the certificate front, that your site is using Cloudflare has nothing to do with the certificates used for mail.com's mail servers. You should only disable certificate checks if you have a *very* specific reason for doing so - "because it makes it work" is not a valid reason.

## Update:

You're sending from a gmail address without sending through gmail - that will fail SPF checks. If you want to send From a gmail address, you *must* send through gmail, not your ISP.

Unlikely to be a factor here, but you're using an old version of PHPMailer - upgrade to 6.0.

Comment: I have updated the logs. I did not see a problem. do you have a look?

Comment: Does it have to be the same also with the sending SMTP user?

Answer (score 0):

1-change this sections

```
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
  $mail->Host       = "example";
  $mail->Port       = 25;
  $mail->Username    = "example@example.com";
  $mail->Password    = "example";
```

to =>>

```
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port       = 465;
  $mail->Username    = "your account in gmail";
  $mail->Password    = "your password account in gmail";
```

2-and add this section:

```
  $mail->isHTML();
```

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. already working code. but mail is not going to be mailed to an account on mail.com despite successful writing.